# Refresh ol.layer.heatmap KML every 2 Seconds and Update Layer

Tags: setinterval, heatmap, openlayers-3

I use OpenLayers Heatmap and I want to refresh the KML Vector every 2 seconds. So I thought it would be possible just to delete the Layer, refresh the Layer and then add the Layer in the map again. But nothing worked so far.

Here is my script:

```js
var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
     url: 'tweets.php',
     format: new ol.format.KML({
         extractStyles: false
      })
  }),
blur: parseInt(6, 10),
radius: parseInt(4, 10)
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
   source: new ol.source.Stamen({
   minZoom: 3,
   maxZoom: 8,
   layer: 'toner'
   })
 });

 var koordinate = 5.9;

 var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: [] ,
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
       dragging: false,
       dragPan: false
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
       center: ol.proj.transform([10.5 , 51.0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
       minZoom: koordinate,
       maxZoom: koordinate,
       zoom: koordinate
    })
 });

 map.addLayer(raster);

 map.addLayer(vector);

 blur.addEventListener('input', function() {
     vector.setBlur(parseInt(blur.value, 10));
 });

 radius.addEventListener('input', function() {
     vector.setRadius(parseInt(radius.value, 10));
 });
```

Edit: This was my best solution for the problem but i don't worked.

```
setInterval(function() {
                vector.loaded = false;
                vector.setVisibility(true);
                vector.redraw({ force: true });
            }, 2000);
```

I've also tried everything with `SetInterval`, but everytime it was not correct or it was wrong.

I think the `ol.layer.heatmap` makes it difficult to solve the problem.

Comment: "*But nothing worked so far*", "*it was not correct or it was wrong*" - you'll have to be more specific than that. At the very least you'll need to include the code you're talking about.

Comment: Ok, I added some of my Code. Maybe somebody can help me now.

Comment: I've never used OpenLayers3 specifically, but I couldn't find any mention of a `redraw` method on `ol.layer.Heatmap` - is it possible that made it up or used OL2 documentation instead of OL3? Anyway, looks like your question is already answered [here on gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/121439/6990). It's often a better place to ask GIS-specific questions.

Comment: How do I use this for my KML? I have some Problems there... Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

`ol.layer.Heatmap` doesn't provide a "redraw" method.

`ol.Map` does offer a `render` method though, which you should be using. consider the Dynamic data example for more insight: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/dynamic-data.html

Comment: Ok I looked at it. But I don't know, how to use this for my vector layer. How can I refresh the map, that the new points in the KML are displayed on the map? Maybe you can help me a little bit more. :)

Comment: @mark96 please update your code example above with the most recent changes you've made to your code. without a better understanding of what you're doing, nobody can assist :)  

for instance, i think that there is no value that's going to be impacted by `vector.loaded` and `vector.redraw()` is not a real method (in openlayers-3).